# Not able to install Gentoo Linux

Tags: gentoo

Here is my situation, when I download Gentoo and start to run it and downloaded the stage III Tarball from links and then tried to extract it a stream of white sentences flows down my screen really fast for about a minute just like in the YouTube tutorial I was viewing. However, after that instead of going to the correct stage it says cannot right not enough space on device and I tried repartitioning it but I'm not sure what device it is talkingaboutHowever, after that instead of going to the correct stage it says cannot right not enough space on device and I tried repartitioning it but I'm not sure what device it is talking about.  Please help

Comment: "No space left on device" typically means your filesystem (e.g. hard-drive partition) is full.  But StackOverflow is for *programming* questions, not Linux installation technical support.

Comment: There is a separate stack exchange site for Linux questions:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think you're ready for gentoo. Maybe play with Ubuntu a bit first.

Comment: Have you tried asking via Gentoo-specific forums? E.g. mailing list, irc, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having this issue, though in general, I truly believe Gentoo Handbook is quite well written and even a newbie can follow it...  Here are some advices that I hope I can give you (most important is, digest the handbook and follow it carefully, not that I'm saying "RTFM", it's just that for Gentoo, handbook is essential and without it, we can get lost if you're just starting).

From my experiences, the "stream of white sentences" I'd presume would be from verbose un-tar'ing your stage3.  Usually, I only want to see the errors so my suggestions is to remove the "v" (i.e. from "tar xjvpf" to "tar xjpf") so that only errors would appear when un-tar'ing.  The caveat to this is that you'll be wondering if it hung or is busy un-tar'ing.  Use Alt-F1 and Alt-F2 (if on console/tty mode back-and-forth) to log in on another TTY and do 'ps -auxf' to see if it's still tar'ing.  If you're using GUI Terminal, just open another tab and 'ps auxf', you get the picture...

Also, learn the commands "df", it'll come in handy.  If you're running out of disk space, perhaps you're trying to install/untar stage3 to your ramdisk (*grin*) rather than your mounted (i.e. "/mnt/gentoo").  Mount your root '/' device to '/mnt/gentoo' and cd to that mounted path then try it (don't forget to mount your '/boot' as well as your proc, dev, sys, etc before you chroot - again, follow the handbook as carefully as you can - oh also, distro such as Debian hybrids including Ubuntu uses symlink to shm, so read that part about 'rm /dev/shm' and follow it carefully; if you're using Gentoo LiveCD, you can ignore that part).

Other useful commands if you're confused (or new to) mounting devices would be to learn to experiment with commands such as 'lsblk' and 'mount' (by itself) to inspect the sizes of your partition (again, use of 'df' comes in handy as well) as well as what is your device (i.e. /dev/sda1 versus /dev/sdb1).  Hint: when you do 'mkfs', use "-L" (or for some file system, it's "-N") to label/name your devices, so that when you use commands such as 'mount' or 'lsblk', you can spot them easier.  If you're using GUI/desktop versions of some distro, hopefully there are tools such as "gparted" which can give you visual information in GUI of your devices which can be helpful.  One think I'd advise you to stay away from if you're just starting, is to avoid RAID (i.e. mdadm) until you're comfortable with how grub/lilo works.  Get your kernel (Gentoo-sources) compiled and MBR written (i.e. grub-install), try booting and have fun first (oh also, if you can avoid GUI like installing Gnome/KDE from the get-go, avoid it as well - you'll get into issues such as "should I use SystemD or OpenRC" and then get hit by the obstacle of some gnome parts needs you to use systemd but you've chosen openrc, and so on).

If I may add my opinions, in my opinion, Gentoo (also Arch and FreeBSD) is an excellent place to start if you want to learn the inside of Linux application workings (library dependencies, why packages are important rather than downloading each libs manually and compile them one by one, etc).  I hope this won't discourage you from switching to another distro, but if it does frustrate you on installation and all you want to do is test-drive Linux, there are much easier distro that you'd not have to understand USE and other compilation mechanisms (if you have an old i586, it makes sense to build it with pick-and-chose libraries so that leaner can be faster, but if you have fast machine, why compile binaries when somebody who is expert at it already have done it for you?).  SUSE and Fedora/RedHat/CentOS used to be the least frustrating for it was able to find/detect hardwares (legacy and new) but these days, I usually tell people, "if you know how to install Windows, you can install Ubuntu" so that too may be a good way to wet your feet.  Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

0_o wow, well.. how about some 411 like size of your hdd and exactly how you partioned it? Linux will look for specific directorys and if missing will instead start to install into the root dir. How you partion is an importent first step. Once you got a generally good partion setup most linux installs will go fine. Most basic tables include /, /home,/var and a swap.